# Got error in Yajra Datatable

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, laravel-5.5

I am using **laravel** and **datatables** version details are:

```
| Laravel 5.5 |
| Yajra/datatables 8* |
```

I always got this error when i try to *query* the data

```
"message": "Method where does not exist.",
"exception": "BadMethodCallException",
```

My Code is below

```
public function getExpensesHistory(Request $request){


        $data = Expenses::with(['expenses' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'type_name');
        },'user' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name');
        }])->orderBy('exp_date','desc')->get(); 

        $datatables=DataTables::of($data);

        $from_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($datatables->request->get('from_date')));
        $end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($datatables->request->get('end_date')));

        if ($end_date  and $from_date) {
            $datatables->where('exp_date','<=',$end_date)->where('exp_date','>=',$from_date);
        }

        return $datatables->make(true);

    }
```

Comment: `where` is part of the query builder so you probably need to call it  before you call `->get` .

Comment: please follow this link  https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/advance-filter

Comment: Your link does not call `get()` on the query builder but you do

Comment: You need to make all query changes within your query only not after getting collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be like as

```
$query = Expenses::query();
$query->with(['expenses' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'type_name');
},'user' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'name');
}]);

$from_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->from_date));
$end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->end_date));

if ($end_date and $from_date) {
    $query->where(function($q) use ($from_date, $end_date){
        $q->where('exp_date','>=',$from_date);
        $q->where('exp_date','<=',$end_date);
    });
}

$data = $query->orderBy('exp_date','desc')->get();
```

Over here I've taken query within variable and all actions are performed on that object